# backbone.js Collection.add() doesn't `construct` (`initialize`) an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="cmd_create_event" name="cmd_create_event" type="button">Create
        a new `Event`</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize : function() {
                console.log("`Event` is initialized. id: " + this.cid);

                this.bind("change:status", function() {
                    console.log(this.get("status") + " is now the value for `status`");
                });

                this.bind("error", function(model, error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            },
            defaults : {
                "status" : 0
            },
            validate : function(attrs) {
                if (attrs.status <= 0)
                    return "invalid status";
            }
        });

        var EventList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            initialize : function() {
                console.log("`EventList` is initialized");
            },
            model : EventModel,
            add : function(event) {
                console.log("`Event` added to `EventList`.");
            }
        });

        var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({});

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var event_list = new EventList();

            $("#cmd_create_event").click(function() {

                // GENERATION METHOD #1:
                /*var event = new EventModel();
                event.set({
                    status : 1
                });
                event_list.add(event);*/

                // GENERATION METHOD #2:
                event_list.add({
                    status : 1
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code there are two methods I'm using to add an `EventModel` to an `EventList`.

Method #1 does fire `EventModel.initialize()`, while Method #2 does not.

The [docs says](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) it's possible to add an object just like Method #2, so, why don't I get the object constructed as if I would `new EventModel()`? Quoting the docs:

> If a model property is defined, you may also pass raw attributes
>   objects, and have them be vivified as instances of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first method, you actually call the constructor of the model

```
var event = new EventModel();
```

With the second method, you just pass `{ status: 1 }` to the `EventList.add` method you defined earlier, which only logs to console and doesn't do anything.

If you call

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.add.call(this, event);
```

In your `EventList.add` method, Backbone creates an new model instance from the passed data and `initialize()` will be called (because you specified a `model` attribute when defining `EventList`).

Comment: I would expect it to know that's my intention, without having to explicitly cal the super `add()`. Yet again, I love OOP! Thanks :)

Comment: well, then you wouldn't be able to overwrite `add()` - if you want to do extra stuff when adding to a collection, consider binding to the Collection's `add` event.

Comment: Right, but now that I think about it - I simply overrided the function, which is not my intention! I'll simply `bind()` to it. Thank you again for that minor clarification.